# Add category settings and thumbnail programatically/in front end

Tags: magento-1.9, category, thumbnail

I'm currently using the below to add a category programatically/in the front end

```
 <?php
 $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
 $category->setName('new_category');
 $category->setIsActive(1);   
 $category->setIsAnchor(0);
 $parentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load("X");
 $category->setPath($parentCategory->getPath());
 $category->save();
 ?>
```

There are 2 settings which i need to be able to add - the setting of `use parent category settings = yes` and the category `thumbnail`

How can this be done with the above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the following lines for that:

```
$category->setCustomUseParentSettings(true);
$category->setThumbnail([image]);
```

The [image] is the name of the image that is located in media/catalog/category/

Comment: Is there a magento page/wiki that states what each category's attribute/setting 'setXXXX' is? So in admin the `Use Parent Category Settings` is `setCustomUseParentSettings(true)` As i need to also set the `displayMode` to staticblockonly and then state which block to use for `CMS block`. Rather than ask another question is this list somewhere?

Comment: You can use every database field and available attributes as a setXXXX command. You just have to camelcase the fieldname (remove the underscore and set the first letter after the _ as uppercase). So display_mode becomes setDisplayMode() and image bcomes setImage().